# CalledFromWrongThreadException:Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views

Tags: android

I tried to change a value of a ListView adapter using a thread, but it throws an exception that is CalledFromWrongThreadException
can anyone call a thread that changes a value of any View element?
here is my code:

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){

    public void run() 
    {
        ap=(ArrayList<Application>) getBoughtApps(android_id);
        adapter1 = new MyCustomAdapter(ap);
        listView = ( ListView ) MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.listview);
            changeAdapter();    
    }
}).start();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First Option :**

use [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) for Updating UI from Non - Ui Thread. change your code as:

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){

    public void run() 
    {
      ap=(ArrayList<Application>) getBoughtApps(android_id);
       Current_Activity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {

           adapter1 = new MyCustomAdapter(ap);
           listView = ( ListView ) MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.listview);
           changeAdapter(); 
          //Your code here..
         }
       });

    }
}).start();
```

---

**Second Option :**

You can use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) instead of a Thread for making Network Operations or if application require to Update Ui from Background. you can change your current code using `AsyncTask` as :

```
private class CallwebTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
{

    protected ArrayList<Application> doInBackground(String... params) 
    {
        ap=(ArrayList<Application>) getBoughtApps(android_id);
        return ap; // Return ArrayList<Application>
    }

    protected onPostExecute(ArrayList<Application> result) {
        Log.i("OnPostExecute :: ", String.valueOf(result.size()));
        //Put UI related code here
        adapter1 = new MyCustomAdapter(result);
        listView = ( ListView ) MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.listview);
        changeAdapter(); 
    }
}
```

and to start `AsyncTask` put this line where you are starting Thread:

```
new CallwebTask().execute();
```

---

Comment: @Khalid : just update UI elements within  runOnUiThread and do rest of task in Thread

Comment: @Khalid : what you are doing within changeAdapter() and getBoughtApps(android_id) ? if you are doing any network or haeavy task then move these part out of  runOnUiThread's run method

Comment: I download images from Internet in getBoughtApps(android_id)
so I want to do that in a thread in order to avoid blocking the application while downloading

Comment: @Khalid : then just move `ap=(ArrayList<Application>) getBoughtApps(android_id);` line outside runOnUiThread method.have you try this?

Comment: yes, but the application blocks while downloading
I want to run the downloading function in a thread

Comment: @Khalid : it is not possible but if you have any issue with this code then best way is use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and in  AsyncTask's doInBackground method just place ap=(ArrayList<Application>) getBoughtApps(android_id); and return ap from doInBackground. for updateing UI use `onPostExecute(Result)` with latest values.you can make a search here for AsyncTask then you will find lot of post's

Comment: @Khalid : most welcome friend !!! :).if you have any problem in implementing `AsyncTask` then comment here then i will try to convert your current code using `AsyncTask`

Answer (score 1):

Views can only be accessed by UI threads. You can try the same from runonUIThread block

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
          ap=(ArrayList<Application>) getBoughtApps(android_id);
        adapter1 = new MyCustomAdapter(ap);
        listView = ( ListView ) MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.listview);
            changeAdapter();   
    }
});
```